# Certain functionality doesn't work with `normal!`

Tags: cursor-movement, normal-mode

I always have problems selecting visual areas with the `normal!` command in vim. Against all I expected, the following doesn't work:

```
function! s:foo()
    normal! v/\S\<cr>
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> a :<c-u>call <sid>foo()<cr>
```

It just selects nothing. `normal!` doesn't seem to work with `/`. Have I reached the limit of vim's capabilities or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than using vim key-descriptions (such as `<CR>` or `<C-v>`) you'll have to enter the literal key you want to press. `\<CR>` *looks* like it means "Press the enter key" it *really* means "Search for `\<` start of word, followed by the text `CR>`

To do a literal newline character instead of `<cr>`, try pressing `<C-v><cr>`. This will appear as `^M`. That works for me.

Comment: I don't search for a backslash character, the ` \ ` was supposed to escape the `<` of `<esc>`. All these different kinds of newlines still trip me up...

Comment: @hgiesel oh. So what exactly are you searching for? You should describe that.

Comment: Just what you wrote: Select from current position to first non-whitestace character (inclusive). But with ^M it still doesn't work for me, weird.

Comment: @hgiesel That's because you've got the extra backlash in there. Does it work with `:normal! v/\S^M`? (With ^M entered `<C-v><cr>`)

Comment: @hgiesel Glad I could help! let me update my answer real quick so it more accurately represents the right solution.